# Julia/Flux creating a model correctly - using Chain Embedding layer reshaping & Dense layers

Tags: julia, flux, word-embedding

I am trying to follow an old article about word embedding in Julia language with Flux: https://spcman.github.io/getting-to-know-julia/deep-learning/nlp/flux-embeddings-tutorial-1/

As it is an old outdated article I managed to handle the embedding layer correctly using the new embedding layer of Flux (0.13.11). The Chain looks like this:

```
embedding = Flux.Embedding(vocab_size => max_features, init=Flux.glorot_normal)
model = Chain(embedding(Flux.onehotbatch(reshape(x, pad_size*N), 0:vocab_size-1)),
           x -> reshape(x, max_features, pad_size, N),
           x -> mean(x, dims=2),
           x -> reshape(x, 8, 10),
           Dense(8, 1),
)
```

When I try to check the model my calling model(x) I get:
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Matrix{Float32} are not callable
Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.

My guess that the problem somehow connected to the reshaping.
I am new to both Julia & Flux so sorry if the question is basic.

Any clue what should I do?

Comment: Looks like the first entry in Chain is a matrix not a function. Maybe you want 
`Chain(x -> Flux.onehotbatch(vec(x), 0:vocab_size-1), embedding, x -> reshape(x, max_features, pad_size, N), `... where NB the layer `embedding` is an element of the Chain, rather than being closed over in the `x -> (stuff)` anonymous function.

Comment: This did the trick - the model now evaluates, 
Thank you